# neo4jclient where clause not putting in parameters

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I'm having an issue with the Where clause not pulling out the values and putting them as parameters.

```
return 
   startingNode
   .StartCypher("startNode")
   .Match(matchQuery)
   .Where<TSourceNode>(otherStartNodes => otherStartNodes.Id != startingNode.Data.Id)                
   .Return<TSourceNode>("otherStartNodes").Results;
```

The Query string comes out looking like "WHERE (Id <> Id)". I can fix the problem easily by not using lambdas and just using the code below but I'm interested to see why it didn't work

```
.Where("startNode.Id <> otherStartNodes.Id")
```

I've also tried the below line but that didn't work either.

```
.Where<TSourceNode, TSourceNode>((otherStartNodes, startNode) => otherStartNodes.Id != startNode.Id)
```

**Edit**
Tatham - I've created an issue in Bitbucket for this.

You are correct the right way for the Where clause should be.

```
.Where<TSourceNode, TSourceNode>((otherStartNodes, startNode) => otherStartNodes.Id != startNode.Id))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update: This is [issue 73](https://bitbucket.org/Readify/neo4jclient/issue/73/where-clause-not-building-correctly-with), fixed in 1.0.0.525 and above.**

From what I understand of your rather dynamic query, the third option you mentioned (`.Where<TSourceNode, TSourceNode>((otherStartNodes, startNode) => otherStartNodes.Id != startNode.Id)`) is the correct one.

This should work. I even added more unit tests in Neo4jClient to assert that it does: https://bitbucket.org/Readify/neo4jclient/commits/cc73ce253ddce89e69785caa68f5e4660a622b96

Can you explain why you think it didn't work? What was the resulting query text?

---

The value you're getting for `.Where<TSourceNode>(otherStartNodes => otherStartNodes.Id != startingNode.Data.Id)` is wrong. It should evaluate `startingNode.Data.Id` once in .NET, then send something like `WHERE otherStartNodes.Id <> {p1}` over the wire. I'll test this separately.

Comment: The resulting query text produced the same "Where(Id <> Id)" when I used the 'correct one'.  The issue maybe due to TSourceNode is a generic type and it isn't correctly qualifying the name?  The project I'm working on is open source so I'll add in a test and send you over a link to it. Cheers.